# Placing bounties and accepting answers

Tags: discussion, bounty

If I answer a question, then think "Oh what a clever boy am I!" and decide to put a bounty to award the answer, can I? My initial belief would be no, because it's redundant.

However, if I place a bounty on another person's question, which they (the original asker) then answer, can I award them  the bounty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may place a bounty on a question you answered, but it will not be able to be awarded to your own answer. You can't reward your own answers on someone else's question, either. You are certainly free to reward someone else's self-answer, though.

Comment: Thought so, thanks for confirming